# Using command line arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I have the following code where I try to access the command line arguments but I am having trouble doing so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    int fd = open("drawing.ppm", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0700);

    char colour[] = "0 0 0 ";
    if(argv[1] == "red") {
        char colour[] = "255 0 0 ";
    }

    printf("%s\n", &argv[1]);
    int date = write(fd, colour, sizeof(colour));

    close(fd);

}
```

When I run the code, the terminal displays  `1▒` which is some weird unexpected symbol. Can someone please tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: It's `char **argv`, and you need to use `strcmp()` to compare strings, for a start.

Comment: `char colour[] = "255 0 0 ";` is only "visible" in the `if(argv...)` scope, it does not change the `colour` from the outer scope. And you should use `strcmp` for comparing strings.

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

First your signature for `main()` is wrong it should be

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Notice how `argv` is an array (pointer) of strings not chars.

Second you don't check to see if there were any args passed.

Something like

```
if (argc > 2)
```

Third your printout is the address of `argv[1]` instead of `argv[1]`

Try (inside/after the `argc` check)

```
printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
```

Comment: You should also point out that even if `argv[1]` is `"red"`, this code will still write `"0 0 0 "`, because the second declaration of `colour` is only valid inside the `if` scope.

Comment: And please also point out that `argv[1] == "red"` compares pointers, not the contents and that `strcmp` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

you declare 2 times colour variable take care of that the second one is local to the if-scope.

Comment: This was a good observation that none of the other answers addressed. This answer doesn't deserve an downvote. UV from me.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `argv[1]` is `char*` and you try to use with the operator `==` which is useful for string type variables. Here you are comparing two pointers, in fact, two memory addresses.

You may try to use `strcmp` to compare the contents of objects pointed by the pointers.

Comment: `==` cannot be used for comparing "string type variables" in C